# How can I subset a data frame for cases matching on all but 2 variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a data set in which a subset of participants repeated some condition combinations. I would like to create a single data set with just the conditions that have two repetitions, so that I can check reliability and consistency. So the final data set will only contain subjects and conditions that were done twice, so with a first rep value and a second rep value.

Example data:

```
Data <- structure(list(Sub = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L), .Label = c("1", "2", "4", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"
), class = "factor"), Sys = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), Samp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", 
"T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), Cond = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Rep = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Score = c(92.6666666666667, 77.6666666666667, 
106.333333333333, 47.3333333333333, 70.3333333333333, 48.6666666666667, 
96.6666666666667, 51.6666666666667, 80.3333333333333, 55.3333333333333, 
55.6666666666667, 22.3333333333333, 71.6666666666667, 31.6666666666667, 
74.3333333333333, 15.6666666666667, 67.3333333333333, 48.6666666666667, 
54.6666666666667, 41.3333333333333, 74, 54, 97, 72.3333333333333, 
26.625, 7.5, 5.25, -1.5, 6, -33, -8.25000000000001, -32.25, 19.875, 
4.5, 9.75, 5.625, -16.5, -21, 18.375, -16.5, -16.875, -18, -18.375, 
0.375, 0, 0, -17.25, -18, 68.3333333333333, 51, 102, 85.3333333333333, 
64.3333333333333, 50.3333333333333, 93.3333333333333, 104.333333333333, 
27, 76, 50, 44, 81, 91, 59.3333333333333, 91.6666666666667, 80.6666666666667, 
32.6666666666667, 96, 67, 42.3333333333333, 49.3333333333333, 
71, 63.3333333333333, 59, 47.3333333333333, 70.3333333333333, 
67.3333333333333, 56.3333333333333, 60.3333333333333, 115.333333333333, 
112.333333333333, 36.3333333333333, 80.3333333333333, 40.3333333333333, 
97, 87, 100.333333333333, 61.6666666666667, 104, 71, 28.6666666666667, 
88, 29.6666666666667, 47.6666666666667, 25.6666666666667, 62.6666666666667, 
35.6666666666667, 109, 66.3333333333333, 112, 39.6666666666667, 
69.6666666666667, 98.3333333333333, 74, 40.6666666666667, 47.3333333333333, 
75.6666666666667, 43.6666666666667, 74.3333333333333, 43, 75, 
39, 73.6666666666667, 68.6666666666667, 36.3333333333333, 107.666666666667, 
41, 98.6666666666667, 65.6666666666667, 74.6666666666667, 75.6666666666667, 
68.3333333333333, 68.3333333333333, 41, 51, 100, 102, 78, 85.3333333333333, 
36.3333333333333, 27, 88, 76, 45.3333333333333, 50, 37, 44, 37.3333333333333, 
59, 34.3333333333333, 47.3333333333333, 72.3333333333333, 70.3333333333333, 
67.6666666666667, 67.3333333333333, 56, 36.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 
80.3333333333333, 61, 40.3333333333333, 78.6666666666667, 97, 
67.6666666666667, 109, 67.3333333333333, 66.3333333333333, 97, 
112, 70.6666666666667, 39.6666666666667, 40.3333333333333, 47.3333333333333, 
95, 75.6666666666667, 71.6666666666667, 43.6666666666667, 72.6666666666667, 
74.3333333333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -168L
))
```

If I look at just the number of rows of the repeated conditions I see 24 observations:

```
Data %>% 
    filter(Rep == 2) %>%
    nrow()
[1] 24
```

If I look at just the first reps I see 144 observations:

```
Data %>% 
    filter(Rep == 1) %>%
    nrow()
[1] 144
```

If I try the `_join` functions from `dplyr` I get back more than just the matched cases; I get 48 rows returned:

```
Joined_Data <- right_join(Data %>% 
                 filter(Rep == 1) %>%
                 rename("Score_1" = Score) %>%
                 select(-Rep),
               Data %>% 
                 filter(Rep == 2) %>%
                 rename("Score_2" = Score) %>%
                 select(-Rep),
               by = c("Sub", "Sys", "Samp", "Cond")) 


nrow(Joined_Data)
[1] 48
```

This seems to be because each row is duplicated:

```
head(Joined_Data)
  Sub Sys Samp Cond   Score_1   Score_2
1   1   1   T1    C  68.33333  68.33333
2   1   1   T1    C  68.33333  68.33333
3   1   2   T1    C  51.00000  41.00000
4   1   2   T1    C  51.00000  41.00000
5   1   1   T2    C 102.00000 100.00000
6   1   1   T2    C 102.00000 100.00000
```

I can drop the duplicates by passing the tibble through `distinct()`, but the approach seems messy.

Passing the above through `distinct()` does give the **desired output**

```
Joined_Data <- right_join(Data %>% 
                     filter(Rep == 1) %>%
                     rename("Score_1" = Score) %>%
                     select(-Rep),
                   Data %>% 
                     filter(Rep == 2) %>%
                     rename("Score_2" = Score) %>%
                     select(-Rep),
                   by = c("Sub", "Sys", "Samp", "Cond")) %>%
                 distinct()

   Sub Sys Samp Cond   Score_1   Score_2
1    1   1   T1    C  68.33333  68.33333
2    1   2   T1    C  51.00000  41.00000
3    1   1   T2    C 102.00000 100.00000
4    1   2   T2    C  85.33333  78.00000
5    1   1   T1    D  27.00000  36.33333
6    1   2   T1    D  76.00000  88.00000
7    1   1   T2    D  50.00000  45.33333
8    1   2   T2    D  44.00000  37.00000
9    7   1   T1    C  59.00000  37.33333
10   7   2   T1    C  47.33333  34.33333
11   7   1   T2    C  70.33333  72.33333
12   7   2   T2    C  67.33333  67.66667
13   7   1   T1    D  36.33333  56.00000
14   7   2   T1    D  80.33333  83.33333
15   7   1   T2    D  40.33333  61.00000
16   7   2   T2    D  97.00000  78.66667
17  11   1   T1    C 109.00000  67.66667
18  11   2   T1    C  66.33333  67.33333
19  11   1   T2    C 112.00000  97.00000
20  11   2   T2    C  39.66667  70.66667
21  11   1   T1    D  47.33333  40.33333
22  11   2   T1    D  75.66667  95.00000
23  11   1   T2    D  43.66667  71.66667
24  11   2   T2    D  74.33333  72.66667
```

Then I can `gather` this tibble back into a long format:

**Desired output:**

```
Joined_Data %>%
    gather(Rep, Rating, Rating_1:Rating_2) %>%
      separate(Rep, c(NA, "Rep"), sep = "_", remove = T )

       Sub Sys Samp Cond Rep     Score
    1    1   1   T1    C   1  68.33333
    2    1   2   T1    C   1  51.00000
    3    1   1   T2    C   1 102.00000
    4    1   2   T2    C   1  85.33333
    5    1   1   T1    D   1  27.00000
    6    1   2   T1    D   1  76.00000
    7    1   1   T2    D   1  50.00000
    8    1   2   T2    D   1  44.00000
    9    7   1   T1    C   1  59.00000
    10   7   2   T1    C   1  47.33333
    11   7   1   T2    C   1  70.33333
    12   7   2   T2    C   1  67.33333
    13   7   1   T1    D   1  36.33333
    14   7   2   T1    D   1  80.33333
    15   7   1   T2    D   1  40.33333
    16   7   2   T2    D   1  97.00000
    17  11   1   T1    C   1 109.00000
    18  11   2   T1    C   1  66.33333
    19  11   1   T2    C   1 112.00000
    20  11   2   T2    C   1  39.66667
    21  11   1   T1    D   1  47.33333
    22  11   2   T1    D   1  75.66667
    23  11   1   T2    D   1  43.66667
    24  11   2   T2    D   1  74.33333
    25   1   1   T1    C   2  68.33333
    26   1   2   T1    C   2  41.00000
    27   1   1   T2    C   2 100.00000
    28   1   2   T2    C   2  78.00000
    29   1   1   T1    D   2  36.33333
    30   1   2   T1    D   2  88.00000
    31   1   1   T2    D   2  45.33333
    32   1   2   T2    D   2  37.00000
    33   7   1   T1    C   2  37.33333
    34   7   2   T1    C   2  34.33333
    35   7   1   T2    C   2  72.33333
    36   7   2   T2    C   2  67.66667
    37   7   1   T1    D   2  56.00000
    38   7   2   T1    D   2  83.33333
    39   7   1   T2    D   2  61.00000
    40   7   2   T2    D   2  78.66667
    41  11   1   T1    C   2  67.66667
    42  11   2   T1    C   2  67.33333
    43  11   1   T2    C   2  97.00000
    44  11   2   T2    C   2  70.66667
    45  11   1   T1    D   2  40.33333
    46  11   2   T1    D   2  95.00000
    47  11   1   T2    D   2  71.66667
    48  11   2   T2    D   2  72.66667
```

This seems like a lot of clunky steps, so I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to subset the data to only only have specific cases that have 2 scores (one from the first rep, one from the second) and disregard/drop cases with only 1 rep/score.

Is there a cleaner/better way to accomplish the above?

Comment: What is your expected output? If you want rows with only two repetitions doesn't `Data %>% 
    filter(Rep == 2)` already give you what you want ?

Comment: your question is very confusion , please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want correctly, I believe this will do the trick:

```
Data <- Data %>% unique()

Data %>% 
  group_by(Sub, Sys, Samp, Cond) %>%      # check the number of rows for each combination of Sub, Sys, Samp and Cond
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
  filter(cnt > 1) %>%          # filter out groups with just one row and then remove the count column 
  select(-cnt) %>%         
  left_join(Data, by = c('Sub', 'Sys', 'Samp', 'Cond'))
```

Comment: The score for the first rep is missing with this approach.

Comment: I thought that was the goal to be honest, then I didn't quite get what you wanted. Let's say you have the case, which I'll add in the next comment, which rows do you want to get at the end?

Comment: structure(list(Sub = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "4", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), class = "factor"), 
    Sys = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Samp = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", 
    "T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), Cond = c("D", "D", 
    "D"), Rep = c(1L, 2L, 1L), Score = c(43.6666666666667, 71.6666666666667, 
    43.6666666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .Names = c("Sub", "Sys", "Samp", "Cond", "Rep", "Score"
))

Comment: The final result in my original question is the desired output. I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: The edited version gives me 72 rows of output, rather than the desired 48. There are only 24 cases with a second repetition.

Comment: did you get rid of the duplicated rows first, by running the first line of code ```Data <- Data %>% unique()```?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is what you want.

NB: I'm going for the `data.table` approach, you could as well modify it for `dplyr`, though one simple merge for me seems cleaner than those long pipes :)

```
require(data.table); require(magrittr)
Data <- as.data.table(Data)

merge(x = Data[ Rep == 1, .(Sub, Sys, Samp, Cond, Score)] %>% .[!duplicated(.), ],
      y = Data[ Rep == 2, .(Sub, Sys, Samp, Cond, Score)],
      by = c('Sub', 'Sys', 'Samp', 'Cond'),
      all.y = T, suffixes = c('_1', '_2'))
```